# How to access properties that are restricted in EL / JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, el

I have this line in one of my JSPs:

```
<fmt:message key="label.user.request.type.${requestEntry.key.class.simpleName}"/>
```

Used to work perfectly up until I upgraded Jetty to v9.2.2. Now I guess the JSP library has been updated, which makes java reserved words (like `default`, `class` etc illegal identifiers.

The above code comes from rendering a `Map`, and I use the `getClass()` getter - which by some sort of magic becomes `.class.` - which is a reserved word.

**I'm kind of stuck - how can I get around this problem?** I'd rather not refactor the entire file, since the current implementation is pretty neat and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

If there ARE ways of making this work, please let me know. I ended up creating a getClazz() getter in the class used as a key in this map, and then just using that instead.

However, I find this workaround a tad bit hacky - would be nice to reference this getter some other way. So if you have another solution, please let me know.

Comment: Why not just make a  .getClassName() instead?

Comment: Could just as easily do that I guess :)